# Bitcoin Core on external SSD in OS X

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, macos-big-sur, solid-state-drive

I am in Mac OS X Big Sur and would like to run Bitcoin Core on an external SSD for the first time, to download the blockchain. [According to instructions](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-osx.md), the default location for the blockchain is `/Users/${USER}/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/`. How do I change this, so the blockchain is stored in an external SSD? For example `/Volumes/My SSD`?

Comment: Why is this voted down? It is a programming question. I already compiled Bitcoin Core from source and cannot continue programming unless I download the blockchain. Am I correct?

Comment: Read the documentation. [Configuration file path](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/853ac47705c8abd9b8bda2da59eb043d9591491c/doc/bitcoin-conf.md#configuration-file-path).

Comment: Though that solution isn't a programming solution. The programming solution would be to [modify the code](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/8805e0666318f52bc9c29a104fb257268964667a/src/util/system.cpp#L803).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how. Assuming you are in `/Users/{User}/Bitcoin` where Bitcoin Core was compiled:
`./src/bitcoind -datadir="/Volumes/My SSD/Bitcoin"`